# gsutil ls command gives "OSError: Permission denied"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, permission-denied, gsutil

My gsutil is at 4.48 and python is at 2.7.5.

Tried "gsutil ls" and getting the above mentioned error.

**sh-4.2$** cd /root/google-cloud-sdk/bin/

**sh-4.2$** ls -lah

total 63M

drwxrwxrwx 3 root root  222 Mar 25 16:49 .

drwxrwxrwx 9 root root  329 Mar 25 16:49 ..

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5.8K Mar 24 02:38 gcloud

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5.9K Feb 14 20:54 gsutil

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5.8K Mar 24 02:38 java_dev_appserver.sh

**sh-4.2$** gsutil ls

OSError: Permission denied.

**sh-4.2$** python -V

Python 2.7.5

**sh-4.2$** gsutil version

gsutil version: 4.48

**sh-4.2$**

Any help here guys??

Comment: Which user are you using (whoami)? Also, don't post your errors as screenshot. It makes it not searchable and annoying to read.

Comment: Thanks updated the question.
So this is on a kubernetes pod. I tried to log in to the pod using "kubectl exec -it <podid> -c app -- /bin/sh"

and whoami gives me 
sh-4.2$ whoami
user39705

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this.  In my case, the problem was that because I installed `gsutil` as root during the container build, and was running the container as a different user, `gsutil` didn't have rights to its own state directory.  I fixed it by adding the following lines to my Dockerfile:

```
# Permissions needed for gsutil and the gcloud CLI
RUN mkdir -p /.config
RUN chown -R 1234 /.config
RUN mkdir -p /.gsutil
RUN chown -R 1234 /.gsutil
RUN echo "[GSUtil]\nstate_dir=/.gsutil" > /.boto
RUN chown -R 1234 /.boto
```

You'll have to run `whoami` at the command line to figure out which ID you'll need to use instead of 1234 (or look at the USER directive in the Dockerfile).

Once I did this, I was able to use both `gcloud` AND `gsutil` with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the account from the Kubernetes cluster. In that context is not authenticated with the GCP and will not be authorized.

You have a couple of options to authenticate.
1) If you are using GKE, you can enable [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity).

2) Export a Service Account and store it as a Secret like [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform).

3) In the context of the container, you can create a configuration file for gsuil. You may use this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config).

Comment: Hi, I am authenticating using gcloud auth activate-service-account <service account credentials json> and in the document you mentioned for gsutil config it says " Cloud SDK users should use the gcloud auth group of commands instead, which will configure OAuth2 credentials that gcloud implicitly passes to gsutil at runtime."

Comment: It says this explicitly which is what I am doing.. "Note that if you are using gsutil through the Cloud SDK, you should instead activate your service account via the gcloud auth activate-service-account command."

Comment: If you try running "gsutil ls" with the service account, in another context? Like in an instance or Cloud Shell?
I have tried running on GKE using the google/cloud-sdk:latest image and I could "gsutil ls".

Comment: I tried the same from my local machine setting the auth using gcloud auth activate-service-account and gsutil ls works. But on my kubernetes pod when I do this it gives above error.

Comment: does "gcloud auth list" gives the same output in both contexts?